# How to draw clothoids graphically in Qt?

Tags: c++, math, qt4

I am trying to build an application which the user can use to draw clothoids with the mouse, i.e. to set the start point and the end point of the spiral and then by dragging these points with the mouse he could also set the shape of the clothoid by modifying the start and end curvature. Probably for changing the curvature I will need to use the tangents though I am not sure of that.

How can one implement that in Qt? Do you know of any example codes that I could run in Qt?

Comment: In case you still need to solve the clothoid drawing problem, I posted a link to some sample code. Sorry if this is half a year too late. If you found some other efficient sample code in the meantime, I'd be interested to know about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach would probably be to use the [Graphics View Framework](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/graphicsview.html).

There are a few examples that should help you getting started in the [Graphics View Examples](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/examples-graphicsview.html) page. The [Diagram scene](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/graphicsview-diagramscene.html) one looks like a good starting point for what you want to achieve.

Comment: The graphics view framework sounds really good. But how could I draw these segments of clothoid? From what I know in Qt there is cubicTo for Bezier curves but that doesn't work here. I want to draw the curve according to the start and end curvature that is given for the clothoid segment.

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this is an old question, but for interested parties there is a good discussion of theory and pseudocode for Euler spirals (clothoids) in the paper **"Euler Spiral for Shape Completion"** by Kimia, Frankel, and Popescu. Sample C++ code can be found online at Brown University's website.

[Euler Spiral for Shape Completion](https://vision.lems.brown.edu/content/euler-spiral-shape-completion)

[Page with download link for C++ code for method of Kimia, Frankel, and Popescu](http://vision.lems.brown.edu/content/available-software-and-databases)

Papers by Levien and others suggest methods to improved upon the "biarc" calculation of the paper by Kimia, et al. Levien's paper includes an in-depth history.

[The Euler spiral: a mathematical history by Raph Levien](http://levien.com/phd/euler_hist.pdf)

You only need four parameters to draw the spiral: two end points, and the angles of tangents at those end points. (You don't need to define curvature.) The code outputs the intermediate points between the two end points at distance increments of your choice. You simply need to plot and connect those intermediate points.

Once you implement the code, you may need to tweak some of the parameters such as the minimum curvature. You'll likely see a few parameters for which the code "blows up".

Comment: Did you manage to find any more efficient code? The C++ code you linked to looks like it's using an iterative search to find the solution. What I need is something which runs in rapid, constant time.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to tinker with this in a while. The Levin paper had a faster approach, from what I remember.

Comment: Also: "3D Euler Spirals for 3D Curves." http://cgm.technion.ac.il/people/Gur/papers/2012/12-HT-CGTA.pdf