# How to draw a curve in Qt?

Tags: qt4, qwt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to draw clothoids graphically in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828359/how-to-draw-clothoids-graphically-in-qt)

I am trying to draw some curves in my application and I would like to know the best method to do that. The curves are actually segments of clothoids and I know the start and end point for each of them as well as their start and end curvature.

I was thinking of using QWT to plot the curves but I need to calculate all the points on the curve for that.

Is there some other (easier) way to draw the curves?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of curves you need? [Graphics view system](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.7/graphicsview.html) provide many different ways to draw stuff, and with [QPainter](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.7/qpainter.html) you can manually draw anything.

Comment: the curves are segments of clothoid (also called Euler Spiral). they are not normal curves

Comment: I think you are best off doing the components needed for it (sorry I don’t know math enough I could write example code very fast), using either of those systems. Graphics view is much more frexible and is more higher level, so you most likely need only to implement the math. Please make an answer with the code too.

Comment: Oh, and also: this is duplicate, shame on you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828359/how-to-draw-clothoids-graphically-in-qt